# Como pegar a data e hora mínima do dia com LocalDateTime

Tags: java, datetime

Eu tenho essa dataHora no banco de dados:

```
21/07/18 15:52:00,000000000
```

Quando a consulta passar por parâmetro um `LocalDateTime`, quero listar todas as datas que inicia o dia. Como pegar a data minima com o `LocalDateTime`, e fazer a consulta desses dados? Lembrando que tem no banco de dados os milissegundos.

Eu tentei fazer o:

```
 LocalDateTime.Now().MIN
```

Porém dessa forma a data vem errada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MIN` é uma constante que representa o menor valor possível para um `LocalDateTime` ([veja a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MIN)). Mais precisamente, ela representa 1 de janeiro do ano **-999999999** (ano "menos 999 milhões") à meia-noite. Talvez por isso a data tenha vindo errada no seu teste.

Baseado no título da pergunta ("Como pegar a data e hora mínima do dia com `LocalDateTime`"): "**data e hora mínima do dia**" não faz muito sentido, pois uma data representa um dia específico e não tem como ter uma "data mínima do dia".

Enfim, entendi que na verdade você quer a "hora mínima do dia", de determinada data. Ou seja, meia-noite de determinado dia (já que o dia começa à meia-noite, e portanto esta seria a "hora mínima", ou seja, o menor valor possível para a hora do dia).

Para isso você pode usar o método `with` passando um `LocalTime` que corresponde à meia-noite. Este método é útil caso você tenha um `LocalDateTime` qualquer e precise mudar seu horário para meia-noite:

```
// data e hora atual
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
// mudar horário para meia-noite
LocalDateTime inicioDia = dateTime.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
```

Mas se você precisar construir um objeto que corresponde ao dia de hoje e setar o horário para meia-noite, também pode fazer isso usando um `LocalDate` para construir a data (dia, mês e ano) atual e em seguida usar o método `atStartOfDay`, que retorna um `LocalDateTime` com o horário setado para meia-noite:

```
// data de hoje (dia, mês e ano)
LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
// setar horário para meia-noite
LocalDateTime inicioDia = hoje.atStartOfDay();
```

*`LocalDate` também possui o método `atTime`, que permite que você passe um `LocalTime` com o horário que quiser (caso precise de algum valor diferente de meia-noite)*.